# Switch method annotations on/off with spring boot profile

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I'm wondering if there is a way to define and use an annotation only for a specific spring boot profile. Let's imagine I have a method class `foo` with an annotation `'@Bar'` defined:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @Bar()
 Response foo() {}
```

I would like to define `'@Bar()'` annotation (available from a 3rd library) only for a specific profile (production). I would like to skip it when the profile 'dev' is active.